# Overriding Attributes values in Shortcode Plugins

Tags: plugins, shortcode

I have made some shortcode plugins according to my need. But this time I am getting a strange problem. My attributes in the shortcode are not getting the values written in the shortcode while executing them, instead I am just getting the default set values only. Please Help me.

```
add_shortcode('wi_form' , 'wi_form_func');

function wi_form_func($input) {
    extract(shortcode_atts( array(
        'productName'  => 'Java',
        'productPrice' => 1000
    ), $input));
    return $productName . esc_attr($productPrice);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try not to use capital letters in the shortcode attributes, use for example

```
[wi_form product_name="php" product_price="888" ]
```

where:

```
add_shortcode( 'wi_form' , 'wi_form_func' );

function wi_form_func($input) {
    extract(shortcode_atts( array(
        'product_name'  => 'Java',
        'product_price' => 1000
    ), $input));
    return $product_name . esc_attr( $product_price );
}
```

or this:

```
add_shortcode( 'wi_form' , 'wi_form_func' );

function wi_form_func($input) {
    $input = shortcode_atts( array(
        'product_name'  => 'Java',
        'product_price' => 1000
    ), $input );
    return $input['product_name'] . esc_attr( $input['product_price'] );
}
```

if you don't want to use `extract`:

### Update:

The shortcode attributes go through `strtolower()` in the `shortcode_parse_atts()` function that retrieves them from the shortcode tag ([see here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/shortcodes.php#L243)).

Comment: @user2046703 : if you put `var_dump($input);` at the top of your callback you will see that your attribute names come back all lowercase-- `productName` becomes `productname`. There is an explicit note in the Codex about this behavior: ["Attribute names are always converted to lowercase before they are passed into the handler function."](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Attributes)

Comment: @s_ha_dum thanks for the link. I updated the answer with a link to the source where the parsed attributes are taken through the  `strtolower()` function.

Comment: Thanks birgire,
Got my mistake.. and completed the target! :)

Comment: ok great, please mark the answer as accepted if this solved your problem thanks.